# Lyx not rendering some integral symbols

Tags: lyx

I have been using Lyx for a long time. Recently I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and LyX Version 2.3.4.2. Everything is working fine, however I have noticed that the `\oiintop` symbol is not being shown in Lyx. Let me illustrate the problem:

[image]

On the top there is the Lyx interface and at the bottom the generated PDF. As can be seen the PDF is exactly what I want. However the integral symbol is not rendered by Lyx, which is annoying. This is only happening with `\oiintop`, other commands such as `\intop`, `\iintop`, `\iiintop`, `ointop` are working fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you load any math (and math-font) packages?

Comment: Not sure, but try `sudo apt-get install fonts-lyx`

Comment: @Fran ```fonts-lyx``` is already installed. @Mico I have all the packaged configured to load automatically.

Comment: Maybe some wrong in Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Screen Fonts ? and in >>> Display > Instant Preview > On? Anyway,  I would  try to reinstall fonts-lyx, reconfigure and  restart lyx. At worse, you would only lose a few seconds.